# "where is not null' can't work in mysql workbench

Tags: excel, csv, mysql-workbench

In continent column has null value....but when I use where condition like "where continent is not null".but it always shows null value. So how can I fix it????

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your column is not really NULL it has an empty string. You can check that if you check against an empty string `continent = ""`. When this is working you should check the value of your column if the column is really NULL.

Normally the apps show you a NULL value in the output with a `NULL`.

Comment: How to solve now????

Comment: if it's an empty value then check against the empty value or set the fields where the string is empty to NULL.